# Ipython/Jupyter Notebook HTML misaligned when viewing mobile browser

Tags: python, html, css, ipython, jupyter

`Windows 8.1, Python 3.4, Jupyter Notebook`

I'm using a custom CSS stylesheet hosted on github to render the notebook in HTML. When I download as `HTML` and look at the file on my desktop browser, the code, text, markdown and images are aligned and formatted properly. However when I view the same notebook on a mobile browser the notebook appears to have a massive left margin padding and is no longer aligned properly with the background.

Any help solving this problem would be greatly appreciated. I've attached image samples and my Jupyter/IPython CSS Stylesheet for reference. Thank you.

**On Desktop Browser**

[image]

**On Mobile Browser**
[image]

My Ipython/Jupyter Notebook CSS Stylesheet is copied below:

```css
<style>
    div.cell{
        width: 1000px; /* altered from 850px*/
        margin-left: 0%!important; /*altered from 10%*/
        margin-right: 5%; /*altered from auto%*/
    }
    /*div.text_cell{added from frankcleary.com but didn't look great for current setup
        margin-top:-2px;
        margin-bottom:-2px;
        padding-top:2px;
        padding-bottom:2px;
        border-left:2px solid #505050;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        border-top:none;
        border-bottom:none;
    }*/
    h1 {
        font-family: "Open sans",verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    }
    .text_cell_render h1 {
        font-weight: 200;
        font-size: 40pt;
        line-height: 100%;
        color:#447adb;
        margin-bottom: 0em;
        margin-top: 0em;
        display: block;
        white-space: nowrap;
    } 
    h2 {
        font-family: "Open sans",verdana,arial,sans-serif;
        text-indent:1em;
    }
    .text_cell_render h2 {
        font-weight: 200;
        font-size: 20pt;
        font-style: italic;
        line-height: 100%;
        color:#447adb;
        margin-bottom: 1.5em;
        margin-top: 0.5em;
        display: block;
        white-space: nowrap;
    } 
    h3 {
        font-family: "Open sans",verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    }
    .text_cell_render h3 {
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 18pt;
        line-height: 100%;
        color:#447adb;
        margin-bottom: 0.5em;
        margin-top: 2em;
        display: block;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    h4 {
        font-family: "Open sans",verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    }
    .text_cell_render h4 {
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 16pt;
        color:#447adb;
        margin-bottom: 0.5em;
        margin-top: 0.5em;
        display: block;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    h5 {
        font-family: "Open sans",verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    }
    .text_cell_render h5 {
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: normal;
        color: #1d3b84;
        font-size: 16pt;
        margin-bottom: 0em;
        margin-top: 1.5em;
        display: block;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    div.text_cell_render{
        font-family: "Open sans",verdana,arial,sans-serif;
        line-height: 135%;
        font-size: 125%;
        width:750px; /* altered from 750px */
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        text-align:justify;
        text-justify:inter-word;
    }
    div.output_subarea.output_text.output_pyout {
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        max-height: 300px;
    }
    div.output_subarea.output_stream.output_stdout.output_text {
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        max-height: 300px;
    }
    div.output_subarea.output_html.rendered_html {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        max-width: 100%;
        overflow-y: scroll;/* was commented out */
        max-height: 300px;/*  was commented out   */
    }
    code{
      font-size: 78%;
    }
    .rendered_html code{
        background-color: transparent;
        white-space: inherit;   
    }
    ul{
        /* color:#447adb; */  
        margin: 2em;
    }
    ul li{
        padding-left: 0.5em; 
        margin-bottom: 0.5em; 
        margin-top: 0.5em; 
    }
    ul li li{
        padding-left: 0.2em; 
        margin-bottom: 0.2em; 
        margin-top: 0.2em; 
    }
    ol{
        /* color:#447adb; */  
        margin: 2em;
    }
    ol li{
        padding-left: 0.5em; 
        margin-bottom: 0.5em; 
        margin-top: 0.5em; 
    }
    /*.prompt{
        display: None;
    } */

    ul li{
        padding-left: 0.5em; 
        margin-bottom: 0.5em; 
        margin-top: 0.2em; 
    }
    a:link{
       font-weight: bold;
       color:#447adb;
    }
    a:visited{
       font-weight: bold;
       color: #1d3b84;
    }
    a:hover{
       font-weight: bold;
       color: #1d3b84;
    }
    a:focus{
       font-weight: bold;
       color:#447adb;
    }
    a:active{
       font-weight: bold;
       color:#447adb;
    }
    .rendered_html :link {
       text-decoration: none; 
    }
    .rendered_html :hover {
       text-decoration: none; 
    }
    .CodeMirror{
            font-family: "Source Code Pro", source-code-pro,Consolas, monospace;
        }    
    .rendered_html :visited {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .rendered_html :focus {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .rendered_html :active {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .warning{
        color: rgb( 240, 20, 20 )
    } 
    hr {
      color: #f3f3f3;
      background-color: #f3f3f3;
      height: 1px;
    }
    blockquote{
      display:block;
      background: #f3f3f3;
      font-family: "Open sans",verdana,arial,sans-serif;
      width:700px; /*altered from 610px*/
      padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; /*altered from 15px 15px 15px 15px*/
      text-align:justify;
      text-justify:inter-word;
      }
      blockquote p {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        line-height: 125%;
        font-size: 100%;
        text-align: center;
      }
    div#notebook_panel {/* added from theming w/ Hammond */
        box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        border-top: none;
    }
   /* element.style {
    } */  
</style>
<script>
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
                        TeX: {
                           extensions: ["AMSmath.js"]
                           },
                tex2jax: {
                    inlineMath: [ ["$","$"], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
                    displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"], ["\\[","\\]"] ]
                },
                displayAlign: "center", // Change this to "center" to center equations.
                "HTML-CSS": {
                    styles: {".MathJax_Display": {"margin": 4}}
                }
        });
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is the dropbox link to the HTML file produced by IPython/Jupyter when downloaded as an HTML file.

[Dropbox HTML file download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0i2qejec65g68qp/blackarbs_AAPL_report_sample_2.html?dl=1)

Comment: It's hard to know what causes this without seing the html as well as the css. It could be the hard coded pixel widths. Use media queries or relative sizes for small screens. Instead of `width:750px;` you can try `width:0.75vw;`, for instance. It's also possible that one of your tables can't fit on the small screen, and that can increase the size of the containing element as well.

Comment: @FaustoNA I added a dropbox link to download the HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not what you are looking for at all, but what if you place a div around the entire code and set it's margin to auto?

Alternatively, you could set a master div around the content to:

```
width: 70vw;
```

You would then have to create two divs for either side of the master and set each to:

```
width: 15vw;
```

In this way, divs take up the entire width, and will always remain in proportion no matter what screen it's on.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround would be to do this:

- Use Media queries for smaller screens.
- Try to stick with Bootstraps grid system instead of going for the traditional approach of manually applying the margins and padding.(looking at the HTML file, found out that you used bootstrap).
- Envelope the div content(the one which has all the text) into a div/container and apply a negative margin CSS to the content(not the container), something like this :

  `media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width:768px){
    #container #some-div{
      margin-left: -50%;
    }
  }`
- Use `em` instead of `px`.

What this will do is shift the entire text part towards the left when it is opened in mobile device.

You can also add a `position: absolute; top: -10%;` to the above code, just to test it out.

Hope it helps...

Comment: HTML/CSS isn't my strong suit. Can you please show me as an example with the CSS file I uploaded in my question?

Comment: Giving an example would be difficult because it will take some time to know what exactly is going on in the html and css files you have given. And there is another thing what I dont understand, when you you are using bootstrap, you could have used to the bootstrap grid instead of the normal approach.This would have solved most of the alignment problems.

Comment: I took a preexisting CSS and made a couple small changes. The HTML is generated by default from Jupyter NBConvert. I'm not sure what bootstraps grid system is but would implement it if I knew how

Comment: you should check this out first: [http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)